# How to make write-host recognizable on TFS?

Tags: powershell, tfs

`write-verbose` prints out whatever output from PowerShell onto the TFS logging screen, but `write-host` doesn't.

What I like about `write-host` is the `-foreground color` option it has.

So I would like to retain the colors and hence I ask:

I've tried `write-host` but nothing gets printed out on the TFS logging.

How can I configure TFS logging to accept/recognize `write-host` just like it recognizes `write-verbose`?

Comment: `Write-Host` is [usually discouraged](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/AvoidUsingWriteHost.md) for output.  In your case the issue is that (as the [official help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-6) states):  "The particular result depends on the program that is hosting PowerShell"

Comment: @boxdog what does this mean: "The particular result depends on the program that is hosting PowerShell"

Comment: It means you can't rely on it working the same everywhere, since the data is sent to the 'host', which is responsible for how it is displayed.  So, just because `Write-Host` works pretty much the same in the console, ISE, VSCode, etc, doesn't mean it will elsewhere (e.g. TFS).

Comment: @boxdog but its the only one that has the colors :(

Comment: @boxdog also why is there security reasons the write-host is discouraged? the article doesnt state much

Comment: I'm not sure there are 'security' reasons not to use it.  It's mainly avoided for the reason you're seeing, that it is not processed via the PowerShell pipeline, but by the host, so is potentially unreliable/inconsistent.  Where did you see the security stuff?

Comment: @boxdog it says: Severity Level: Warning

Comment: Azure Pipelines shows Write-Host in it's logging, but without coloring. In the end coloring will have to be implemented by the final front-end, in this case the build system's web UI. So while you may be able to get TFS to show Write-Host also, the coloring support is highly unlikely.

Comment: @DhruvMurarka well if i can at least configure the TFS to somehow start recognizing write-host, this way for local testing i can at least see the coloring for easy debugging on my end, i'd be fine with that. plus, it'd save me a lot of time instead of having to change all write-hosts to write-verbose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution for the narrower requirements in the comments: Make TFS show `Write-Host` output without colors, continue having colors on local, and don't change all the `Write-Host` calls in code to something else.

The solution is to redefine `Write-Host` only for the TFS environment, such that calls to `Write-Host` end up using some supported `Write-` command (like `Write-Verbose` or `Write-Output`).

So you can add this to the start of your powershell script:

```
if($Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER) {
    function Write-Host($object) {
        Write-Output $object
    }
}
```

Note there is an important limitation in this approach: If any function uses `Write-Host` and then returns some value, it's return value will include whatever was sent to `Write-Host`. For example, compare the value of `$x` before redefining `Write-Host` and after:

```
function test() {
    Write-Host "hi"
    return "bye"
}
$x = test
```

To avoid this, you can also use `Write-Verbose` or any other `Write-` instead of `Write-Output`, but they don't work well for non-primitive types. They will either error out or just show the type name. You can do `$object.ToString()` inside the `Write-Host` redefinition to prevent errors, but often that may just show the object's type name.

More info on TFS env variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=azure-devops

Comment: What am I supposed to use for build number? Or I dont have to do anything, just paste that in my script? $Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER ... the document doesn't explain much regarding this env variable. Also, I have param and cmdlet bindings, which have to be at beginning of a ps script. Does that function have to really be at beginning or it just should go before any write hosts? Btw thanks so much for looking into it!

Comment: Just before any write hosts, and you shouldn't have to do anything for the environment variable. The only use of the environment variable is to distinguish between TFS and local (it won't be set in local).

Comment: I see. I was confused because I thought I have to define the build number somewhere in system variables or something. Is build-buildnumber primitive to TFS? Like something it would pickup?

Comment: Yes, it'll be available in the script automatically. Maybe this is a better resource than in the answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Yep, there it is: This variable is agent-scoped. It can be used as an environment variable in a script and as a parameter in a build task, but not as part of the build number or as a version control tag.